# c#: System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I can't figure out why i'm getting this error ... it occours in the line with `for(...)`, at the time the Expression `f < fehler.Count` is false

- if `fehler.Count=0` then it crashes directly
- if `fehler.Count>0` then it crashes when `f=fehler.Count`

does anybody know why? it doesn't make sense to me

even though i encapsulated it in try-catch, the app crashes

```
try
{
    if (jsonObject["errors"].ValueType == JsonValueType.Array)
    {
        JsonArray fehler = jsonObject["errors"].GetArray();
        for (int f = 0; f < fehler.Count; f++)
        {
              res.errors.Add(fehler[f].GetString());
        }
   }
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

if i set a break-Point on the line within the for-loop, then it doesn't reach this Point, so the error definitly occours in `for (int f = 0; f < fehler.Count; f++)`

thanks for any help!

EDIT:

> LW_V1.exe!LW_V1.App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__2(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Zeile 50   C#
>       [Externer Code] 
>       LW_V1.exe!LW_V1.Views.Auftrag.AuftragZuweisenStart(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e) Zeile 433  C#
>       [Wiederaufnehmen der asynchronen Methode]
>       [Externer Code]

this is a screenshot of the exception:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5F458A8ACB00BE93!62968&authkey=!AN1hn_1hXEZncJ4&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG

Comment: Can you include the stack trace, so we can see exactly where the exception is being thrown from.

Comment: You may have something wrong, I tried with `JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse("{ \"errors\" : [] }");`  and it perfectly worked.